# De una lista que dejare abajo, quiero sumar los elementos de la lista en la posición 2 donde los elementos de la lista sean iguales en la posición 0

Tags: python, estructuras-de-datos

```
l=[('ABRBRO3004', 'A000014', 30), ('ABRBRO3004', 'A000016', 25), ('ABRUNA6005', 'A000005', 1000), ('CLASTA1017', 'A000009', 20), ('DESGAL6003', 'A000013', 5), ('IMPERM6022', 'A000005', 25), ('LAMINO3047', 'A000013', 2), ('MUFNEW9004', 'A000005', 1), ('MUFNEW9004', 'A000015', 50), ('TUEHEL5021', 'A000013', 22), ('VARCOR1002', 'A000009', 5), ('VARCOR1002', 'A000015', 15), ('VARCOR1002', 'A000017', 5)]
```

Hasta ahora he intentado esto para poder agrupar y después sumarlo pero nada de exito.

```
  for g in l:
        if g[0]==g[0]:
            u.append(g)
        else:
            n.append(g)
        
    for i in n:
        print('NO ES IGUAL',i)

    for i in u:
        print('IGUAL EN LA POSICION [0]',i)
```

Un output por poner un ejemplo seria algo así.

('ABRBRO3004', 'A000014', 30)

('ABRBRO3004', 'A000016', 25)

Total=55

('ABRUNA6005', 'A000005', 1000)

('CLASTA1017', 'A000009', 20)

('DESGAL6003', 'A000013', 5)

('IMPERM6022', 'A000005', 25)

('LAMINO3047', 'A000013', 2)

('MUFNEW9004', 'A000005', 1)

('MUFNEW9004', 'A000015', 50)

Total=51

('TUEHEL5021', 'A000013', 22)

('VARCOR1002', 'A000009', 5)

('VARCOR1002', 'A000015', 15)

('VARCOR1002', 'A000017', 5)

total=25

Comment: El código que has puesto no parece guardar relación con el problema. Para empezar `g[0]==g[0]` va a ser a siempre cierto, ya que estás comparando un dato con él mismo. Por otro lado los bucles finales que imprimen PAR e IMPAR no tienen nada qué ver con el resto del problema y en la salida de ejemplo que muestras no aparece nada sobre par o impar.

Comment: Así lo estoy probando y me da el error que tu dices, lo puse por poner algo por que se que no es así, por eso mismo estoy buscando otras alternativas, lo de impar y par pues se supone que en par guardo los elementos que son iguales en la posición [0] para después  sumarlos y en impar los que no son iguales en dicha posición.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piensa que no puedes catalogar un elemento en la lista "pares" o "impares" la primera vez que te lo encuentras, pues no sabes si volverá a aparecer en alguno de los elementos siguientes (en cuyo caso debería ir a la lista `n`) o si no volverá a aparecer más (en cuyo caso debería ir a la lista `u`).

Sólo tras haber procesado todos los elementos de `l` podrás saber si cada dato en posición 0 apareció repetido o no.

La estructura de datos adecuada para realizar esta primera pasada sobre los datos sería un diccionario. Este diccionario tendría una clave para cada valor que encuentras en posición 0 (y si esa clave ya estaba en el diccionario es que aparece repetido). En cada una de las claves se guardará una lista con los datos correspondientes. Si al final la lista asociada a esa clave tiene un solo elemento, es que la clave apareció sólo una vez. Si tiene varios elementos es que apareció varias veces.

Veamos cómo se construiría este diccionario:

```
resultado = {}
for dato in l:
  if dato[0] not in resultado:
    resultado[dato[0]] = []
  resultado[dato[0]].append(dato[2])
```

Observa cómo se mira si el la parte 0 del dato estaba en el diccionario. Si no estaba, se crea y se le asigna una lista vacía. Y después se mete la posición 2 del dato en esa lista (si la lista ya existía porque había sido encontrado antes otro dato, se añadirá a los que había).

Al ejecutar este código en `resultado` tendrás:

```
{'ABRBRO3004': [30, 25],
 'ABRUNA6005': [1000],
 'CLASTA1017': [20],
 'DESGAL6003': [5],
 'IMPERM6022': [25],
 'LAMINO3047': [2],
 'MUFNEW9004': [1, 50],
 'TUEHEL5021': [22],
 'VARCOR1002': [5, 15, 5]}
```

Ahora ya es posible hacer otro bucle que recorra este diccionario separando los casos que aparecen una sola vez (la lista asociada tiene longitud 1) de los que aparecen varias veces, creando así las listas `u` y `n` que pretendías:

```
n = []
u = []
for clave, valores in resultado.items():
  if len(valores) == 1:
    u.append((clave, sum(valores)))
  else:
    n.append((clave, sum(valores)))
```

En estas listas vamos metiendo tuplas de dos elementos. El primer elemento es la etiqueta y el segundo es la suma de los valores (funciona también si la lista tiene un solo elemento), pero esa tupla la guardamos en la lista `u` o en la lista `n` según haya 1 solo valor o más de 1 en esa clave.

Una vez separados así ya podemos imprimir los resultados:

```
print("PARES")
for clave, valor in n:
  print(clave, valor)
print()
print("IMPARES")
for clave, valor in u:
  print(clave, valor)
```

Sale:

```
PARES
ABRBRO3004 55
MUFNEW9004 51
VARCOR1002 25

IMPARES
ABRUNA6005 1000
CLASTA1017 20
DESGAL6003 5
IMPERM6022 25
LAMINO3047 2
TUEHEL5021 22
```

Comment: Ufff excelso compañero, muchas gracias en verdad te lo agradezco, estaba perdidisimo la verdad Jajaja, tengo que seguir practicando mi logica de programacion y esperamos algun dia llegar al nivel tuyo, un saludo.